# Android Facebook SDK confusion, why "!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()"?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}
```

Referring to the code above, what is "!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()" doing?

Why could that clause be true? What is the intention?

Comment: it is seeing if there is a active session if yes then utilize that else start new session

Comment: @IllegalArgument but why not just using if (! session.isOpened){...} else {...}

Comment: If the session is opened and not closed, it will open the active session. Otherwise it creates a new session

Answer (score 1):

If the session is 'opening' then it will enter the else condition.

Comment: Thanks. So "opening" and "opened" are treated the same?